# Is there a workaround for the Firebase Query "IN" Limit to 10?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have a query for firebase that has an array of IDs that has a size > 10. Firebase has restrictions on the number of records to query in one session. Is there a way to query against more than 10 at a time?

> [Unhandled promise rejection: FirebaseError: Invalid Query. 'in' filters support a maximum of 10 elements in the value array.]

https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/queries

[image]

```
  let query = config.db
    .collection(USER_COLLECTION_NAME)
    .where("id", "in", matchesIdArray);
  const users = await query.get();
```

(matchesIdArray.length needs to be unlimited)

Comment: Did you found the way how to solve your problem? As I have the same question.

Comment: @Ramis what I did was have a counter on the number of returned results. Once I hit ten, i would break, save the ten results into a map, and then re-query minus the values in the map.

Comment: @Olivia would you be able to provide an example of your solution?

Comment: For future readers, with the exception of the `not-in` operator, the limit of 10 comparison values was increased to 30 (across your query) with the release of OR queries in March 2023. The change was made available in the following JavaScript SDK versions: `firebase` v9.18.0, `@google-cloud/firestore` v6.5.0, and `firebase-admin` v11.6.0.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I found this to work well for me without needing to make as many queries (loop and request in batches of 10).

```js
export async function getContentById(ids, path) {
  // don't run if there aren't any ids or a path for the collection
  if (!ids || !ids.length || !path) return [];

  const collectionPath = db.collection(path);
  const batches = [];

  while (ids.length) {
    // firestore limits batches to 10
    const batch = ids.splice(0, 10);

    // add the batch request to to a queue
    batches.push(
      collectionPath
        .where(
          firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(),
          'in',
          [...batch]
        )
        .get()
        .then(results => results.docs.map(result => ({ /* id: result.id, */ ...result.data() }) ))
    )
  }

  // after all of the data is fetched, return it
  return Promise.all(batches)
    .then(content => content.flat());
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot OzgurG, that means a lot, my pleasure!

Comment: I want to restrict initial feed output and add up when user scrolls down, does the **batch** can be used to do it?

Comment: Hi @MikeMaus, yes, it can. However, I'd only recommend using this method while scrolling for two reasons:
1) You want to request more than 10 documents at a time

2) you need to query items by their id

Comment: This is really neat! However, Im getting an error at this point: firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId() ... it is saying that firebase can't be found. I have tried .. const firestore = require('firebase/firestore') and then firestore.FieldPath..., const firebase = require('firebase'), const admin = require('firebase-admin') and then admin.firestore ..... but none of these seem to help. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi @Starfs, that's a great question. To get firebase in this case, I used `import * as firebase from 'firebase'` I really hope that's the one for you! If that doesn't work, you may need to do `two` requires --> `const firebase = require("firebase");
// Required for side-effects
require("firebase/firestore");`.  --> additional info can be found here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#set_up_your_development_environment.   Fingers crossed

Comment: Batching like this is a great workaround for the Firestore constraint. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Thanks a lot, HungryAuthur, I'm glad its useful!

Comment: another solution may be flipping the data model and storing membership on the documents you are fetching themselves. then you only need one query to check fetch documents that signal they're members of your group

Answer (score 6):

***BEST METHOD***

convert the list into a list that contains sublists of 10 items each.
then for loop through that second list and query through firebase in each loop.

EXAMPLE:

```
List<String> phoneNumbers = ['+12313','+2323','1323','32323','32323','3232', '1232']; //CAN BE UPTO 100 or more
```

CONVERT THE PHONE NUMBERS TO A LIST OF SUBLIST OF 10 ITEMS EACH

```
List<List<String>> subList = [];
for (var i = 0; i < phoneNumbers.length; i += 10) {
    subList.add(
        phoneNumbers.sublist(i, i + 10> phoneNumbers.length ? phoneNumbers.length : i + 10));
}
```

NOW RUN FIREBASE QUERY

```
subList.forEach((element) {
      firestore
          .collection('Stories')
          .where('userPhone', whereIn: element)
      .get()
      .then((value) {
    
    value.docs.forEach((snapshot) {
      //handle the list
    });

  });
```

Comment: I love this approach but can't seem to figure out how to call it with an id .where('id', whereIn: element) - any idea what to put there?

Comment: instead of userPhone you can use id

Comment: hmm... I have tried that. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 5):

One common way to work around this limitation is to retrieve the items in batches, and then either process the results from each query either sequentially or in parallel.

Another common workaround is to model your data in a way that doesn't require for you to read dozens of documents to handle an individual request from your user. It's hard to say how you could reduce that number, but it often involves duplicating the data that you need from those separate documents into a single aggregated document.

An example of this: if you have a news site and need to show the latest 10 article headlines for each of 5 categories, you can do:

1. Do 50 separate reads, one for each document.
2. Create a document with the headlines for the latest 10 articles, and then only need to read 5 documents (one for each category).
3. Create a document with the latest 10 headlines for all 5 categories, and then only need to read that one document.

In these last two scenarios you're making the code that writes to the database more complex, as it needs to now write the aggregated documents too. But in return you have much less data to read, which reduces the cost, and improves the performance of your app. This type trade-off is very common when using NoSQL databases, which tend to be used in scenarios that have massively more reads than writes of their data.

For more data modeling advice, I recommend:

- [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/)
- [Getting to know Cloud Firestore](https://firestore.video)

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. Like your first suggestions, I think the best route for now is 50 different reads...I am curious though, will I have to `.get()` after each read or can I add to the query like so: `query = query.where("id", "==", matchesIdArray[i]);`?

Comment: You can do a `IN` query, as Doug's answer shows, and as is documented here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_and_array-contains-any

Answer (score 4):

Your only workaround is to make one query for each item in the array that you would normally use with a single "in" query.  Or, batch the requests in the array.

```
  let query = config.db
    .collection(USER_COLLECTION_NAME)
    .where("id", "==", matchesIdArray[0]);
  const users = await query.get();
```

You'd have to use the above code in a loop over the `matchesIdArray` array, and merge the results after they are all done.

Comment: thanks @Doug. I think this might be my best bet until i move off firebase. It is for a chat feature that is pulling all of the current users's matches and generating single and group chats which is feeling too complex for Firebase at this moment

Comment: my only fear about this is putting a callout in a loop will crash the app.

Comment: if I loop through the array and do: `var usersMatchesCollection = config.db.collection("Users");`
     `var query = usersMatchesCollection;`
      `for (var i = 0; i < matchesIdArray.length; i++) {`
       `query = query.where("id", "==", matchesIdArray[i]);`
      `}`
      `const users = await query.get();` will the id get over written or will it append?

Comment: You won't crash the app unless you make maybe tens of thousands of requests, and the results consume all your available memory.

Comment: Your query won't work because each where clause is a logical AND on top of the last one.  It will match no documents.  You have to make a new query for each one, as I recommended in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm testing this right now and the in operator now supports 30 items in an array

```
const ids = ['1'...'30'] const query = query(collection(db,'posts'))
```

It's possible to use OR in order to create N queries? Maybe someome can show use an example

Comment: Yeah looks like they've changed it, although I couldn't find out in which version.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#limits_on_or_queries

Comment: @Steven The limits were changed on 16 MAR 2023 with the release of OR queries. So the change was released with the following JavaScript SDK versions: `firebase` v9.18.0, `@google-cloud/firestore` v6.5.0, and `firebase-admin` v11.6.0.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and my solution using typescript was :

- for complete observables i used rxjs [forkJoin](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/forkJoin)

```
getPagesByIds(ids: string[]): Observable<Page[]> {
        ids = [...ids];
        if (ids.length) {
            let observables: Observable<Page[]>[] = [];
            while (ids.length) {
                let observable = this.afs.collection<Page>(PAGE, ref => ref.where('id', 'in', ids.splice(0, 10))).get().pipe(map(pages => pages.docs.map(page => page.data())))
                observables.push(observable)
            }
            return combineLatest(observables).pipe(map(pages => pages.flat(1)))
        }
        return of ([])
}
```

- for uncomplete observables i used rxjs [combineLatest](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/combineLatest)

```
getPagesByIds(ids: string[]): Observable<Page[]> {
        ids = [...ids];
        if (ids.length) {
            let observables: Observable<Page[]>[] = [];
            while (ids.length) {
                let observable = this.afs.collection<Page>(PAGE, ref => ref.where('id', 'in', ids.splice(0, 10))).get().pipe(map(pages => pages.docs.map(page => page.data())))
                observables.push(observable)
            }
            return combineLatest(observables).pipe(map(pages => pages.flat(1)))
        }
        return of ([])
}
```

Comment: If anyone having an issue that flat does not exist on type then add:  "es2019" to the lib, like so:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "es2019"
    ]
  }
}

Answer (score 1):

A very common scenario to need more than 10 elements to match an 'in' query is when displaying group chat conversations to all users involved and no one else. So while you may be limited with 10 "members" that can match with that chat ID, why not just reverse the logic and use the "array-contains" query since it is not limited.

Your pseudocode: create an array on every chat document called "usersInvolved" listing the IDs of every user involved and then compare that against the current user's ID.

```
db
.collection('chats')
.where('usersInvolved', 'array-contains', myUserID)
.onSnapshot(...)
```

That will display all the chat conversations for all users in that group conversation, without the limitation of 10 users.

Comment: could you elaborate this more? I think we have a winner answer in here boys!!

Comment: and what will happen if you unfollow  someone? then we need to run a query on the entire posts collection and remove your id for every post?

Comment: and how this will work using real time? aka onsnapshot!

Answer (score 0):

As per the firebase documentation it support up to 10 ids only in the where field, For querying more than 10 elements either we need to query each document individually or split array to chunks of 10 ids.

For querying each items individually. Check the code below,

```
let usersPromise = [];

usersIds.map((id) => {
    usersPromise.push(firestore.collection("users").doc(id).get());
});
    
Promise.all(usersPromise).then((docs) => {
    const users = docs.map((doc) => doc.data());

    // do your operations with users list
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  async getInBatch(query, key, arr) {

      const promises = new Array(Math.ceil(arr.length / 10))
          .fill('')
          .map((_, i) => arr.slice(i * 10, (i + 1) * 10))
          .map((i) => query.where(key, 'in', i).get());
      const batches = await Promise.all(promises);
      const docsData = [];
      batches.forEach((snapshot) => {
          snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
              docsData.push([doc.id, doc.data()]);
          });
      });
      return docsData;
  }
  
  const data = await this.getInBatch(db.collection('collection'),
    'id',
    [1,2,3]
  );
```

For javascript, this was my implementation with promises, using a Promise.all

The first part of the code groups an array into in clauses with sets of 10, and then executes each set of 10 in the Promise.all. The resulting array is returned as a tuple with the docid in the first, and document data in the second part.

Answer (score 0):

Adding my own solution here as I was not totally satisfied with the current answers:

```
docsSnap$(queryFn?: QueryFn): Observable<T[]> {
  return this.firestore.collection<T>(`${this.basePath}`, queryFn)
    .get()
    .pipe(map((i: QuerySnapshot<T>) => i.docs
      .map((d: QueryDocumentSnapshot<T>) => d.data())));
}
getIdChuncks(allIds: Array<string>): Array<Array<string>> {  
  const idBatches = [];
  while (allIds.length > 0)
    idBatches.push(allIds.splice(0, 10));
  return idBatches;
}
processBatches(allIds: string[]) {
  const batches$ = this.getIdChuncks(allIds)
    .map(ids => this
    .docsSnap$(ref => ref.where('id', 'in', ids)));
  this.items$ = forkJoin(batches$)
    .pipe(map(arr => arr.flat()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Dart Implementation of Conrad Davis answer for Flutter to fix firestore Query "IN" (whereIn/whereNotIn) limited to 10

```
Future<List<QueryDocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>> getContentById(
      {required List<Object?> ids,
      required String path,
      required String field,
      bool whereIn = false}) {
    var collectionPath = store.collection(path);
    var batches = <Future<List<QueryDocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>>>[];

    var batch = ids;
    while (ids.length > 0) {
      // firestore limits batches to 10
      var end = 10;
      if (ids.length < 10) end = ids.length;
      batch = ids.sublist(0, end);
      ids.removeWhere((element) => batch.contains(element));

      if (whereIn) {
        // add the batch request to to a queue for whereIn
        batches.add(collectionPath
            .where(field, whereIn: [...batch])
            .get()
            .then((results) => results.docs));
      } else {
        // add the batch request to to a queue for whereNotIn
        batches.add(collectionPath
            .where(field, whereNotIn: [...batch])
            .get()
            .then((results) => results.docs));
      }
    }

    // after all of the data is fetched, return it
    return Future.wait(batches)
        .then((content) => content.expand((i) => i).toList());
  }
```

Use like this:

```
getContentById(ids:["John", "Doe", "Mary"], path: "contacts", field: 'name', whereIn:true)
        .then((value) async {
      for (var doc in value) {
        var d = doc.data();
        //... Use your data Map<String, dynamic>
      }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

The limit has been recently increased to 30. The problem with splitting and all is with pagination and ordering. A difficult take if done via splitting.

Comment: The limit is still 10. Please refer to https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_and_array-contains-any

Comment: The document has not been updated. check your code, increase the number of keys and it would throw a message at you. Please check before giving -ive comments.

Comment: I just tested this myself to be more  using the .where() with `in`, and when the array is more than 10, and I get an error after 10, while anything 10 and below is working. React-Native-Firebase.  Not sure why the docs talk about 30 disjunctions...

Comment: May be its about the version of the library being used. I am using the following libraries and it's working with 30 in conditions.


            
        <dependency>
<artifactId>google-cloud-firestore</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.3</version>         
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
            <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
            <version>9.1.1</version>
        </dependency>