# Firestore whereNotIn Query

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Working with flutter and firestore. I have a collection of widgets. I query these widgets and displaying them to the user one at a time so they can tell me whether they have ever seen this widget in real life before. The query:

```
firestore.collection('widgets').where('docID', whereNotIn: seenBeforeList).get()
```

Where 'seenBeforeList' is a array in the user document to keep track of the widgets they have marked as seen.

Let's say I have 20 widgets. The user has marked the first 11 widgets as seen and closes the app. Next launch the query says, give me all the widgets that the user hasn't already seen (the last 9). Essentially, I don't want to show the widgets the user has already marked as seen. However firestore has the, 'value.length <= 10' - filters support a maximum of 10 elements in the value [List], rule so after the user marks the first 10 widgets (seenBeforeList) this query fails.

I can't seem to think of a different solution. Maybe a different data structure...I'm not sure. Am I missing something? Any thoughts would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds lame but I think the usual suggested solution is to just loop for 10/n times and aggregate the gets into one list you then await. This is also the solution I would personally go with

```dart
// Note, haven't tested this code at all
Future<List<QuerySnapshot<T>>> getNotInList(
  List<String> seenBeforeList,
) async {
  final snapshotsFutures = <Future<QuerySnapshot<T>>>[];

  for (var i = 0, limit = 10; i < seenBeforeList.length; i++) {
    final ids = seenBeforeList
        .getRange(i * limit, max((i + 1) * limit, seenBeforeList.length))
        .toList();
    // final seenBeforeList = ids.slice(i, i * limit); ?
    snapshotsFutures.add(
      firestore
          .collection('widgets')
          .where('docID', whereNotIn: ids)
          .get(),
    );
  }

  return await Future.wait(snapshotsFutures);
}
```

For a similar question asked in context of react native, there's this [SO answer as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61354866/is-there-a-workaround-for-the-firebase-query-in-limit-to-10). noSQL definitely has some weird limitations but what can you do :\

#### Edit

This will not work as some futures will have results that you don't need for the reason their exclude ids are different from others

Comment: Thanks for that. I think I see what you’re doing. 

Let’s say I had 25 widget docs and the user has already seen 1-15. The first loop would return 11-25, the second loop would return 1-10 & 15-25. Right? Do I understand that correctly and is that was you expect? You could parse the results but I feel like there is a lot of unnecessary reads. Maybe that’s the way it is or am I misunderstanding something? 

E: Definitely understand there are limitations just trying to brainstorm ‍♂️. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Yup, looking at this again, I just noticed this solution might not work. I think I was thinking of an `aggregating` solution but `whereNotIn` implies a not an intersection of results but something else. Sorry, the only other solution (besides a `cloud_function`) I can think of is to get the whole collection and then do your ids removal on the whole thing. I'll give this a second thinking over and see if I can think of anything else

Comment: Yeah that makes more sense. No worries I appreciate the effort! Yeah the whole collection thing works too. Might be the way to go, just thought I would try to avoid the potentially large number of reads from the size of collection it could be. I’ve been thinking of maybe even a different data structure of some kind. Maybe maintaining a sub collection to the user doc of all the widgets which have a field of “seen”. The problem there is if I have 10,000 users and I add a new widget I have to make 10,000 writes. Maybe that’s not a huge problem? I think that’s the opposite of scalability, lol.