# Angularfire workaround to Firebase 'not-in' query limit of 10

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've been working on an admin chat section of my app and I hit a wall with this limit, that I have no idea existed. Until now I was using this function to check for new messages in order to make my notifications:

```
getNewMessages(readMsg:any):Observable<object>{
     return this.afs.collectionGroup('messages', (ref:any) => ref.where("docId", 'not-in', readMsg)).snapshotChanges();
  }
```

Where readMsg is an Array of messages ID's that are already seen and the query pulls only the new messages. Anyhow, now when I start testing I got this error and I really can't figure out how to restructure my function. I saw this threat `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61354866/is-there-a-workaround-for-the-firebase-query-in-limit-to-10`, but I am not sure how is this applicable to Angularfire and the hole Observable concept.

Comment: You have to do exactly what is discussed in that other question: make multiple queries in batches of 10.  There are no other workarounds.  The limit applies to all clients in all languages - it's enforced on the backend.  If you're having problems with that, then you should make an attempt, show what you have so far, and explain where you are stuck or what isn't working the way you expect.

Comment: I don't think this question is exactly a duplicate, since the OP is referring to `not-in`  and not `in`. 

In the later case, you can query in badges and merge the results, but in the former the merge will not be correct, but the intersection. It'd be nice to have some code ready for that