# Firestore strategy for excluding items the user has already seen

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, database-design

Imagine a tinder-like app.

- Users see a feed of items, and rate some of them
- The feed is loaded in batches of 20 items
- Each batch should include the latest items, but exclude the ones the user has rated

So, I first load the collection of the user's rated items, and then:

```
const itemsCollection = await firebase.firestore().collection('items')
        .orderBy('id')
        .where('id', 'not-in', userRatedItems)
        .orderBy('publish_date', 'desc')
        .limit(20)
        .get();
```

The problem is that 'not-in' is [limited](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/queries#in_and_array-contains-any) to searching in a list of 10 items, and the user's past ratings could be in the thousands.

I could theoretically load all rated items, and remove them from the list of candidates, but:

1. I don't know how many items to query for, since I don't know how many will be excluded as already rated
2. I have a feeling that there is a better strategy for what I am trying to do

Comment: Firestore doesn't support that atm. There are a few workarounds listed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70858469/is-there-a-workaround-for-the-firebase-query-not-in-limit-to-10) but I doubt if they can scale well.