# Workaround for firebase “IN” limit of 10 compatible with onSnapshot?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I have run into the firebase “IN” limit of 10.  Although a workaround solution was already answered here:

[Is there a workaround for the Firebase Query "IN" Limit to 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61354866/is-there-a-workaround-for-the-firebase-query-in-limit-to-10)

None of the solutions in that thread seem to work with the listener “onSnapshot”.  For my use case (Vue 3), I have a composable/function call I that queries firebase passing in an array that could have up to 100 document ID values and returns an object as below.

Is this possible?

```
import { ref, watchEffect } from 'vue'
import { db } from '@/firebase/config'
import { collection, onSnapshot, query, where, documentId } from 'firebase/firestore'

const getUsersList = (idList) => { 
    // idList is an array of document ID's
    const documents = ref(null)
    let collectionRef = collection(db, 'users')
    collectionRef = query(collectionRef, where(documentId(), 'in', idList))
    // this fails if I pass in more than 10 elements in the array
    const unsub = onSnapshot(collectionRef, snapshot => {
        let results = []
        snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
            results.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })
        })
        // update values
        documents.value = results
    })
    watchEffect((onInvalidate) => {
        onInvalidate(() => unsub())
    })
    return { documents }
}

export default getCollectionRt
```

Comment: You really should skip using "in" altogether and just set up listeners on each individual document.  There is no real cost or performance hit in doing so, and it will simplify your code.  If you have some specific requirement to use "in", then you should state that in your question. Otherwise, your question is really no different than the original you liniked to - it's the exact same problem with the same solutions that use listeners instead of consuming the results directly.

Comment: I'd be good with that but could you show an example with multiple listeners that return a single object containing the results from all of them as was asked?

Comment: Why do you need listeners at all if you just want one result?  If that's all you want, just `get()` each document separately.

Comment: I want one result that updates if the underlying data updates hence the use of onSnapshot and subject of this post.

Comment: It's going to be a lot of work to put that together, whether or not you use several "in" queries or, use individual document listeners.  There won't be a single query listener that can do it all.

Comment: Correct, "...an array that could have up to 100 document ID values" would need up to 10 listeners I would assume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no replies here completely answered the question, I ended up paying a freelancer to take a look and here's what they came up with.  The solution does seem to have a random issue I am trying to sort out when the underlying changes, one of the records will disappear.  It does work, is in scope of the original question and seems to have solved the problem.

```
import { ref, watchEffect } from 'vue'
import { db } from '@/firebase/config'
import { collection, onSnapshot, query, where, documentId } from 'firebase/firestore'


const getUserList = (idList) => {
    console.log('idList', idList)
    let documents = ref(null)
    let collectionRef = collection(db, 'users')

    let unsub, unsubes = [], resultsList = [{}];
    for (let i = 0; i < idList.length; i += 10) {
        let idList1 = idList.slice(i, i + 10); //console.log(idList1);
        let collectionRef1 = query(collectionRef, where(documentId(), 'in', idList1))
        unsub = onSnapshot(collectionRef1, snapshot => {
            let results = []
            snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
                results.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })
            })
            resultsList.splice(resultsList.length, 0, ...results);
            console.log('results', results)
            documents.value = results
        })
        unsubes.push(unsub);
    }
    watchEffect((onInvalidate) => {
        onInvalidate(() =>{ unsubes.forEach(unsub => { unsub();         console.log("unsut", unsub); }) });       
    })
    Promise.all(unsubes);
    resultsList.shift(0);
    console.log("docu", documents.value);
    return { documents };
}

export default getUserList
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to initialize multiple listeners i.e. same number of queries but with `onSnapshot()` (might be better than setting up a listener for each individual document). Try:

```
import { ref } from 'vue';
import { collection, query, where, documentId, onSnapshot } from 'firebase/firestore'

const users = ref({})
const dataLoaded = ref(false)

const addFirestoreListeners = async () => {
  const idList = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < idList.length; i += 10) {
    const items = idList.slice(i, i + 10)

    const q = query(collection(db, 'users'), where(documentId(), 'in', items))

    onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
      if (dataLoaded.value) {
        snapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
          if (change.type === 'added' || change.type === 'modified') {
            users.value[change.doc.id] = change.doc.data()
          } else (change.type === 'removed') {
            users.value[change.doc.id] = null
          }
        })
      } else {
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          users.value[doc.id] = doc.data()
        })

        dataLoaded.value = true
      }
    })
  }
}
```

The `dataLoaded` flag checks if the listeners have fetched data for first time or has received an update. I've use a map where the key is document ID so it can be removed easily but do change that to an array or any other required structure.

Comment: @BGMX my code keep updating same object every time a listener gets an update. You can use `Object.values(users)` to map the data in UI. What are you looking for?

Comment: Would the unsub work the same as the original, even with multiple listeners or would the connection persist?