# Firestore-Flutter: Query with 'whereIn' Greater than 10 items

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a function that takes in a Firestore 'Query', specifically `Query<Map<String, dynamic>>` (not a 'QuerySnapshot'). One of the queries I have to do has an item that is a list that can be >10. I know the 'whereIn' function cannot accept more than 10 items, so is there a way to iterate through the `Queries` and return multiple `Query's` instead of `QuerySnapshots`? Everything works fine when 'teamRecord.usersInTeam.length' is < 10.

```
    FirebaseFirestore
              .instance
              .collection('activity_units')
              .orderBy('activity_value', descending: true)
              .where('challenge_reference', isEqualTo: widget.challenges.reference)
    //the teamRecord.usersInTeam cannot be > 10 and this where the error is thrown
              .where('user_inchallenge', whereIn: teamRecord.usersInTeam.asList());
```

I tried to implement a similar solution for `Snapshots` found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68711077/16806413), but I could not get it work to return a `Query`.

```
Query<Map<String, dynamic>> GetUsersInTeams() {    
List<DocumentReference> usersInTeam = teamRecord.usersInTeam.asList();
          List<List<DocumentReference>> subList = [];
          for (var i = 0; i < usersInTeam.length; i += 10) {
            subList.add(
              usersInTeam.sublist(i, i + 10 > usersInTeam.length ? usersInTeam.length : i + 10)
            );
          }
    
    final results =
          subList.forEach((element) {
           Query test = FirebaseFirestore
                .instance
                .collection('activity_units')
                .orderBy('activity_value', descending: true)
                .where('challenge_reference', isEqualTo: widget.challenges.reference)
                .where('user_inchallenge', whereIn: element);
          });
          return results;
}
```

The error here is below. I am not sure how to make `subList.forEach()` return a `Query`.

```
A value of type 'void' can't be returned from the method 'GetUsersInTeams' because it has a return type of 'Query<Map<String, dynamic>>'.
```

I also tried the following function, and it returned the first 10 records, but not anymore.

```
    int _start = 0;
    int _end = 10;
    
    Query<Map<String, dynamic>> getUsersInTeams() {
        List<DocumentReference> usersInTeam = widget.teamRecord.usersInTeam.asList();
        print('usersInTeam ${usersInTeam.length}');
        if (_end >= usersInTeam.length) {
          _end = usersInTeam.length;
        }
    
        List<DocumentReference> nextUsersInTeam = usersInTeam.sublist(_start, _end);
        print('nextUsersInTeam ${nextUsersInTeam.length}');
    
        final results = FirebaseFirestore
            .instance
            .collection('activity_units')
            .orderBy('activity_value', descending: true)
            .where('challenge_reference', isEqualTo: widget.challenges.reference)
            .where('user_inchallenge', whereIn: nextUsersInTeam);
    
        // Update start and end indices for next query
        _start = _end;
        _end += 10;
     
        return results;
      }
```

Comment: The latest SDKs should actually allow up to 30 items in an IN clause (or across all disjunctions if you use OR too). Are you on the latest SDK?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I am on `cloud_firestore: ^4.7.1`. Should I update to `4.8.0` for that?

Answer (score 1):

The latest SDKs should actually allow up to 30 items in an IN clause (or across all disjunctions if you use OR too). But from looking at the code [here](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/blob/81f1b80c445cfaab3e7752b8c58f35c92d234d8d/packages/cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore/lib/src/query.dart#L734), it looks like the Flutter SDK might not have updated its check yet.

I filed issue [#11085](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/11085) on the FlutterFire repo to track this.

Comment: Thank you. I have confirmed that even `cloud_firestore: 4.8.0` throws the same error.