# How do I query a Firebase collection using WHERE 'not in' an array with more than 10 values?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In other posts, the solution presented for the 10 value limit was to loop and request in batches of 10, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61354866/is-there-a-workaround-for-the-firebase-query-in-limit-to-10). This works fine if the operation is "in", as you can simply remove duplicates in the end.

However, it's absolutely not the case with the "not in" operation.

**Example**: Let's say I have documents with ids from 1 to 21 in a certain collection. (for this example we'll disregard the existence of the ">" or "<" operators).

We have an array of ids we want to ignore in our query, ranging from 0 to 20, and we want to retrieve only one document that escapes that range.

Normally, we would use the "not in" operation and limit our query to 1 document. However, there's a limit of 10 values for the not in array, so we're in a huge pickle.

1. We'll have to split the array in half, one ranging from 1 to 10 and the other from 11 to 20.
2. We can no longer limit our query to 1 document, as the chances of us getting the the same value in both queries are slim.
3. We'll end up having to make 2 queries, retrieve 11 documents in the first one, and 11 documents in the second one. And we'll find the intersection: 21.

So, bottom line, we wasted 22 reads to get 1 document. And the number of reads required to find this intersection will grow exponentially as we have more documents and our blacklist array grows.

So, my question is: Is there really no way around this? Because this is not a solution, it's a (bad) workaround. This honestly feels like a humongous flaw in Firestore, and I'm honestly not sure what I'll do to fix my problem at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `not-in` clauses with more than the maximum number of supported values, I'd do something similar (but not the same) as you do for `in`. Start by querying with the maximum number of values, and then post-filter the documents in your application code to exclude the extraneous values.

Note by the way that I think the limit **may** have been increased to 30 values, as part of the changes when Firestore added support for OR clauses. The documentation still mentions the limit as 10, but give it a try and let me know if you can pass more values (or not).

Comment: Hey Frank, thanks for the feedback. I've really given it some thought, and even if the limit was 30, it wouldn't do me any good, as there would always be a chance the limit could be surpassed. Querying all the values is also not an option, as this type of query will be often used by my users, and my costs would go through the roof. My workaround will be to have a single document with an array field containing all my document ids. That way I'll be able to query all the ids without wasting too many reads, filter after retrieving them and make a single get request afterwards.