# How to filter more than 10 elements when need orderBy time

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have been trying to figure out this problem for many hours but I came with no fruitful idea. To describe my problem:

I have a collection of documents. Each single document in this collection represents a single followed user.

Then I have another collection of documents where each single document represents a single user's post.

The thing I'm trying to achieve is to get all posts ordered by time in descending way by "timestamp" field and only from determined users.

Recently my code looked like this (using swift):

```
     Firestore.firestore()
            .collection("posts")
            .whereField("userUID", in: self.followedUsersList)
            .order(by: "timestamp", descending: true)
            .getDocuments { querySnapshot, _ in }
```

Where followedUsersList was a list of followed users. This list could contain infinite amount of users so with firestore limitations, it is impossible to do it this way due to maximum 10 elements limit.

I saw workaround using batches ([Is there a workaround for the Firebase Query "IN" Limit to 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61354866/is-there-a-workaround-for-the-firebase-query-in-limit-to-10)) but it is extremely inefficient.

Imagine some user would follow 2000 users. Then I would have to split the iteration into 200 single operations and then sort it by a time locally.

Second, if each user would have for instance 200 posts, then I would have to load 200 * 2000 documents each time user refreshes the page. On the other hand, if no one would have a single post, I would still have to make 200 iterations to find it out. With a slow mobile and wifi, this could take even up to minutes, which is unacceptable.

Does anybody have any idea how to do it? I was even trying to find out how to restructure my database, but I came with nothing.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot for both sub-collections. Besides that, the `followedUsersList` is a list that is returned also by a Firestore query?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is almost always to denormalize data, which is just a fancy way of saying that you write duplicate data to match your use-case.

---

So for example, you could have a data model where you store the `feed` for each user, so with all posts of people they follow. Now when the user visits the app, all you have to do is load the documents/posts from their `feed` collection instead of having to gather them from all other user's `posts` collections.

Of course, with this data model you will have to then write the post to each follower's `feed` when it is created (a process known as fan-out). Of course this is also a time consuming operation, but NoSQL databases are built on the premise that reads occurs much more frequently than writes - so the trade-off should be worth it.

---

Duplicating data to match the use-case is very common on NoSQL databases. If you're new to this, I recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and watching [Get to know Cloud Firestore](https://firestore.video).

If you still find it hard to wrap your head around after those, keep in mind that it's totally valid to stay with a relation database and data model if that fits your use-case and/or experience better.

Comment: But it means that each time when user starts/stops following someone, I will need to update the feed? For example if I start following a user with 5k posts, I will need to fetch all of those into my feed? And from different perspective, if user uploads a post and has 2M followers, he will need to make 2M uploads to feeds? Am I saying it right?

Comment: You could, but it all depends. I intentionally did not talk about the initial contents of a feed. Most social networks do a mix between your query-at-visit-time and fanout-at-post-time. But covering that in more depth than I already did is well beyond what we can reasonably cover in a Stack Overflow Q&A, which is why I linked two more extensive resources in my answer and why I pointed out that it is totally fine to stay with a relation database if that better fits your use-case and experience.